# [Javaのビルド・パス]-[ライブラリー(L)]-[Web app ライブラリー]に、別プロジェクトを追加する方法

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[Javaのビルド・パス]-[ライブラリー(L)]-[Web app ライブラリー]に、別プロジェクトを追加したいと思ったのですが、手動でライブラリーフォルダにjarファイルをコピーする方法しかないのでしょうか？

実現したい状態としては下記画像の通りです。↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

手動でjarファイルを配置しなくとも出来る方法について調査しており、
・[プロジェクト参照]を設定する→実行時、NoClassDefFoundErrorが出る
・[Javaのビルド・パス]-[ライブラリー]-[クラス・フォルダーの追加]
・[JavaプロジェクトをTomcatのクラスパスに追加する]
・[デプロイメント・アセンブリー]の設定→上記画像の通りになるが、libには実際にjarは追加されていない状態（原因不明）
などを実際に設定してみたのですが、うまくいっていないのが現状です。
また、別プロジェクトを参照するにあたって、Tomcatのserver.xmlでも何か設定する必要があるような気がしているのですが、今のところ触れていません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「Aプロジェクト」はJavaプロジェクト(JavaのWebアプリケーションでも可能)であることが前提ですが、Javaのビルドパス -> 「プロジェクト」タブを選択 -> 必要なプロジェクトをチェックボックスで選択すればできるかと思いますのでお試しください。

[image: Javaビルドパス設定]
なお、WTPをお使いのようですので、Webデプロイメントアセンブリーに追加する方法があります。

他プロジェクトを参照する側（インポートする側）のプロジェクトを選択 -> プロパティから、デプロイメント・アセンブリーを選択します。

※Eclipseのバージョンによっては現れません。4.xなら表示されるはずです。

デプロイメント・アセンブリーを表示後、追加 -> プロジェクト を選び、インポートしたいプロジェクトを選択すると、jarファイルとしてインポートされます。

この操作をした後は、サーバーから該当するTomcatのサーバーを右クリックし、クリーンないしは更新をして、実際にアプリケーションが展開されているディレクトリを最新化します。

実際に展開されているディレクトリにて、プロジェクト名.jarファイルがWEB-INF/lib/にありますのでご確認ください。

[image: Webデプロイメント・アセンブリー]

Comment: これは既に設定してあるのですが、いざ実行するとNoClassDefFoundErrorが出てしまいます

Comment: なるほど状況がわかりました。回答を更新しましたので確認してください。

Comment: デプロイメント・アセンブリー設定を行ったのですが、libの中にjarが生成されず、実行するとNoClassDefFoundErrorになります。
[ビルド・パス]-[ライブラリーの追加]でWeb appを追加すると、その中には対象プロジェクトが入っている状況です。
jarが生成されない原因などありますでしょうか？

Comment: 確認されたWEB-INF/libは、Eclipseから見た状態ではなく、WTPがPC上で展開しているTomcatのwtpwebappsにある、[プロジェクト名]/WEB-INF/lib で間違いないでしょうか。

jarが生成されない原因としては、あとは私の経験ですが
・両方mavenプロジェクトで、ローカルプロジェクトをmaven経由で取得している
・既に同じ名前のフォルダ（または解凍した同プロジェクト）などが、Eclipse上のWEB-INF/lib に配置しているため、ファイルが重複しているので正しく配置されない。
・プロジェクトの設定ファイル(.classpathや.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.componentなど)にて、対象のプロジェクトがデプロイ対象に含まれていない
などが考えられます。

作業の様子を見ますと、色々とlib以下にファイル配置やプロジェクト配置などをされた後ですので、もう一度プロジェクトの導入からやり直した方が安全かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調査を進めてみます。